# Quectel m66 bluetooth usage?

Tags: bluetooth, gsm, at-commands

I've been working on m66 and got it connected to PC via usb to serial converter, and got it up and running.

```
AT
```

command replies with `OK` response.

But none of the bluetooth commands are working.

In reference to `Quectel_GSM_BT_Application_Note_V1.1.pdf` provided by Quectel.

I've tried

```
AT+QBTPWR=1
```

but it replies with an error code

```
+CME ERROR:100
```

I looked into all reference documentation for this module, but cannot find any refernce to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the modul is under development and bluetooth isn't fully supported. Your problem should be solved in soon with a newer firmware for M66.
[image: http://www.quectel.com/product/prodetail.aspx?id=73]